# Early 2013 Macbook Pro Retina El Capitan Only Getting Internet Recovery

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, partition, internet-recovery

I have a early 2013 Macbook Pro Retina 15 inch running El Capitan 10.11.4.

For work reasons, I need a case sensitive file system so I created a second volume on my hard drive that is formatted as "OS X Extended (Case-Sensitive, Journaled, Encrypted).

I now have sensitive data on this volume so I right-clicked on it on the desktop and selected "Encrypt". That all worked fine and it is encrypted.

Now, however, when I need to boot into recovery (for example to turn off or on SIP), I only get "internet recovery" which downloads a recovery partition from Apple that shipped with my computer (that is, not El Capitan's recovery partition which would let me manage SIP).

My question is -- is there anything I can do to address this issue?
Here is the output of `diskutil list`:

```
tjarrett-unimbp-2013:~ tjarrett$ diskutil list

/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):

   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER

   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *751.3 GB   disk0

   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1

   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            700.9 GB   disk0s2

   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

   4:          Apple_CoreStorage Development             49.3 GB    disk0s4

   5:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s5

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):

   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER

   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +700.6 GB   disk1

                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2

                                 772A616B-C7C0-489C-8881-711203675318

                                 Unlocked Encrypted

/dev/disk2 (internal, virtual):

   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER

   0:                 Apple_HFSX Development            +49.0 GB    disk2

                                 Logical Volume on disk0s4

                                 5485AE68-1527-4314-BDD9-3D858A149C17

                                 Unlocked Encrypted
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So when you hold down the option key at startup, you only get an icon that allows booting OS X? In other words, there is no additional icon labeled something like "Recovery HD"?

Comment: @DavidAnderson I'm not op, but I have the same problem. it automatically starts internet recovery mode. No icons or anything like that

Comment: @Suhaib: If you can not access the [Startup Manager](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204417), then I would suggest you try installing a different manager. One such manager is [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/), which can be downloaded and used for free. I would recommend installing to the EFI partition. As a bonus, rEFInd provides a convenient and faster way to enable or disable System Integrity Protection (SIP).

Comment: I actually had it installed, I wanted to remove ubuntu, so I used gparted from a live use stick. After deleting ubuntu and rebooting, rEFInd menu completely disappeared (auto boot to mac). But now you mentioned it. Its actually a legit solution. ill try googling around to see if I can bring the menu back or else just re-install rEFInd. thanks for the tip @DavidAnderson